# How to install Ubuntu alongside Maveriks?

Tags: system-installation

Someone can tell me if it is possible to create a dual boot Ubuntu/Maveriks. I have Ubuntu 12.04 and it will be nice to have Maveriks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation). You may have to install Mac first, and then use rEFit and Bootcamp to allow the installation of Ubuntu.

The problem is, with Mac you need compatible hardware - https://askubuntu.com/questions/109132/can-i-installl-mac-os-x-lion-on-ubuntu-11-10-pc